# Can i have a baseController that has all my repositories when using StructureMap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap, ioc-container

Historically my controllers have repositories declared on each controller which are injected through StructureMap and this is working fine for me.

But my new project will likely be using the same repositories for each controller.
Due to this i created a BaseController and inherit all controllers from here.
My repositories now live in Base but the injection is not working.

Can it work like this or does constructor injection have to take place on each controller?

---

```
        public static void BootStructureMap()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.Scan(scanner =>
            {
                scanner.TheCallingAssembly();
                scanner.WithDefaultConventions();
                scanner.AddAllTypesOf<IController>().NameBy(type => type.Name.Replace("Controller", "").ToLower());
            });

            x.For(typeof(IGenericRepository<>)).Use(typeof(GenericRepository<>));
        });
    }
```

---

Working:

```
    public class TransactionController : Controller
{
    public IGenericRepository<ITransaction> TransactionRepository { get; set; }

    public TransactionController(IGenericRepository<ITransaction> transactionRepository)
    {
        this.TransactionRepository = transactionRepository;
    }


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var transactions = this.TransactionRepository.Query.AsEnumerable();
        return View(transactions);
    }
```

---

Not working:

```
    public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public IGenericRepository<ITransaction> TransactionRepository { get; set; }

    public BaseController(IGenericRepository<ITransaction> transactionRepository)
    {
        this.TransactionRepository = transactionRepository;
    }

    protected BaseController()
    {

    }
}


public class TransactionController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var transactions = base.TransactionRepository.Query.AsEnumerable();
        return View(transactions);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to inject your repository into `BaseController` somehow. If your last piece of code is the real code you have then it seems that `BaseController` is initialized through protected parameterless constructor.

Add the constructor to `TransactionController`:

```
public TransactionController(IGenericRepository<ITransaction> transactionRepository) : base(transactionRepository)
{
}
```

Comment: I agree, you need to call the constructor on the base class that takes the repository. That said, there is absolutely no benefit in using a BaseController in this scenario.

Comment: @Joshua, agree with you. Only point is that you don't have to repeat a property of your Repository type. But if you have, lets say, 3 controllers - I can live with that. 10 is another story and 100 is orthogonal. But since you have to mention that repo in every constructor of every controller - that is really an extremely low benefit, not to say that you introduced a layer-supertype dependency which slowly kills maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Can use Poor Man's Dependency Injection - used in NerdDinner application

```
public BaseController() : this(new  Message())
{
}
```

Or
Refer Phill's link 
 [tdd-and-dependency-injection-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/07/tdd-and-dependency-injection-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx)

```
Override DefaultControllerFactory 
public class SMControllarFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
```

In

```
application start 
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new SMControllarFactory());
```